# Avoid access to www subdomain on secure server

Tags: ssl, subdomain, certificate, redirection

I have an SSL certificate that is valid for mysite.co.uk but not www.mysite.co.uk it seems. If I use mod_rewrite or .htaccess to redirect from one to the other will this prevent browsers from displaying an invalid certificate security warning if someone tries to access www.mysite.co.uk?

(I've tried redirection but still get the warning if I type https://www.mysite.co.uk directly into the address bar of my browser. I want to know if this is because the redirection isn't working or if the browser will display the warning anyway.)

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the warning anyway because it's trying to make the secure connection even to give the redirect (https://www.mysite, regardless of what it returns).  If you went to http://www.mysite and redirected to https://mysite there wouldn't be a popup.